# How can I suppress the null output of a BufferReader?

Tags: java, null, bufferedreader

Using the following code to split the output of a reader into strings which are then used in a constructor. However when the bufferreader reaches the end of the stream it outputs null, which then causes a null pointer exception in the constructor.

```
List<Pattern> resultList = new LinkedList<Pattern>();
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(r);
    String current;
    while (buff != null) {
        current = buff.readLine();
        System.out.println(current);
        Pattern p = new Pattern(current);
        resultList.add(p);

        }
    return resultList;
```

I've tried putting an if statement to test if the current string is null, however I don't know what to put in the body of the if-clause. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`buff` is never going to be null - it's the return value of `readLine` which is null when you reach the end of the data. *That's* what you need to check, typically with code which assigns the value to a variable and checks it in one go:

```
String current;
while ((current = buff.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(current);
    Pattern p = new Pattern(current);
    resultList.add(p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting an `if` into the `while`, change the conditions of your loop from:

```
while (buff != null)
```

to:

```
while ((current = buff.readLine()) != null)
```

`buff` will not become `null` as a result of reaching the end of the stream, but `current` will become `null` when there is no more input to be returned